# Is it possible to style a label based on what type of input it is for?

Tags: css

I would like to style labels for my dropdown lists differently then other input types but would like to avoid assigning classes to each label. Is it possible to style a label based on what type it is for?

TIA

Comment: Is Javascript an option?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how your html is constructed. If you put the label after the input in the html, you could use the sibling selector in a creative way.

HTML:

```
<div>
<input type="text" value="lorem ipsum" id="lorem" />
<label for="lorem">lorem label</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
<label for="check">check label</label>
</div>
```

css:

```
input[type="text"] + label {
   color: red;   
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
   color: blue;   
}
```

I have set up a small fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/pLCBP/

That said, in real live I would probably put a wrapper div around each input and label 'group', and give it a class that indicates what type of field is inside it, because that makes positioning a lot easier. But as you see, what you ask is indeed possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Option A**
No this is not possible. You should give each label it's own class. Like

```
<label for="test" class="inputText">Name:</label><input name="test" id="test" />
```

CSS

```
.inputText{} // Label
input[type=text]{} // Input
```

**Option B**
What's also an option. Is if you use the label after the input / select. You can do this. This because with the `+` you can select the next element in the DOM. Too bad the `-` is not possible.

```
input[type=text] + label {}
input[type=password] + label {}
input[type=checkbox] + label {}
select + label {}
textarea + label {}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to go about it with Javascript/jQuery, you could run a couple loops to associate labels with their input types, then have the styles handled by classes.

Something like this would work

```
$("label").each(function(){
    var forText = $(this).attr("for");
    $("input").each(function(){
      if($(this).attr("id") == forText){
        var inputType = $(this).attr("type");
        $("label[for="+forText+"]").addClass(inputType);
      } 
    });
  });
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsbin.com/upuguv/1/edit). It could probably be better written, but it would work.